# Android Download Manager get link from HTML and start downloading

Tags: php, android, html, android-download-manager

is there a way to ask Android Download Manager to get the link from  and start download immediately.

Example HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank You</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://domain.com/file.dat" title="Order" download>Download File</a>   
</body>
</html>
```

The current Android Download Manager I'm using

```
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                             Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url); // put here your URL that you get 
                             DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                             request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                             //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
                             request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
                             //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
                             String link = url.toString();

                             String fileName = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                             request.setTitle(fileName);
                             //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
                             request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
                             //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
                             //request.setDestnInExtFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"");
                             downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                             Intent intent = new Intent();
                             intent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
                             startActivity(intent);
                         }
```

Please assist me to modify the code if possible, sorry I am a newbie.

Thank you so much!

Comment: use jsoup for parsing html

Comment: @Madhur thanks for the advise and excuse I am a newbie can you guide more or help me with the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using JSOUP you could use this to get attributes, text,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com")// html page link
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example"
```

Dependencies to add in gradle,

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
```

FOr more eg., http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: I'm using Eclipse actually due to the project requirements

Comment: You're e.g. `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com")` while I changed it to `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); to resolve the error then now it's asking to be `Document doc;
         try {
          doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }` and still the error presist

Comment: your url must return html

Comment: It's a thankyou.php file as a matter of fact does it matter?

Comment: I'm deeply sorry and very thankful for your support. The app is now crashing error "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection cannot be cast to org.jsoup.nodes.Document"

Comment: use this import import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

Comment: required: org.w3c.dom.Document
found:    ord.jsoup.nodes.Document

Comment: I already imported Jsoup so you think I should include org.w3c.dom.Document also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103821/discussion-between-witon-nope-and-madhur).